# How to find frequency of a variable over multiple columns in hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have data regarding gender of people under 8 columns:

```
mem1;mem2;mem3;mem4;mem5;mem6;mem7;mem8
MALE;FMALE;UNKN;MALE;FMALE;FMALE;MALE;MALE
```

Now I want to find out the frequency of male, fmale, unkn using hive.
Something like

```
MALE 4
FMALE 3
UNKN 1
```

I'm new to Hive but I know we need to use group by.
Can someone please help me with the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Hive Reflect to get the counts.

1. Create table having whole line as one column
2. Use Hive Reflection to count number of occurrence on the column. Example

> select reflect("org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils", "countMatches",
>   "MALE;FMALE;UNKN;MALE;FMALE;FMALE;MALE;MALE", "MALE") as Males,
>   reflect("org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils", "countMatches",
>   "MALE;FMALE;UNKN;MALE;FMALE;FMALE;MALE;MALE", "FEMALE") as females
>   from mytable